# LINQ - Specified elements not being removed from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--QTabs Data Storage-->
<SyncTimes>
  <LastSyncTime>
    <id>1</id>
    <SyncTime>3/31/2015 2:03:28 PM</SyncTime>
  </LastSyncTime>
  <LastSyncTime>
    <id>2</id>
    <SyncTime>3/31/2015 2:14:24 PM</SyncTime>
  </LastSyncTime>
  <LastSyncTime>
    <id>3</id>
    <SyncTime>3/31/2015 2:14:25 PM</SyncTime>
  </LastSyncTime>
  <LastSyncTime>
    <id>4</id>
    <SyncTime>3/31/2015 2:14:26 PM</SyncTime>
  </LastSyncTime>
</SyncTimes>
```

All of the above times are earlier today I want to delete all LastSyncTime records before the current time (DateTime.Now):

```
public async void deleteArchivedSyncs()
{
    var xElement = (from element in XMLDocObject.Elements("LastSyncTime")
                    where Convert.ToDateTime(element.Element("SyncTime").Value) < DateTime.Now
                    select element);
    xElement.Remove();
    storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(Settings.xmlFile);
    using (Stream fileStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        XMLDocObject.Save(fileStream);
    }
}
```

This being run does not effect the XML page. The desired elements are not being removed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code and checked what the contents of xElement is?

Comment: @Ulric You can't step through a LINQ statement right? Where can I see all of the values it's stored?

Comment: i don't see using xElement anywhere(writing to file), i think you need to delete from storageFile!?

Comment: @virusivv can you please elaborate?

Comment: you have specified: storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(Settings.xmlFile);
and where do you give the command to remove xElement from your xml string???

Comment: @virusivv Perhaps I'm not. How do you remove the xElement content from the XDocument object before saving?

Comment: you need to wait a little till i find a project of mine with removing elements from xml :S

Comment: @ David Tunnel. Put a breakpoint on xElement.Remove(); Run your code. Click on xElement when it hits the breakpoint. Press SHIFT+F9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue here appears to be that the only way to delete a child, is to have the parent do the deletion, as in:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        // test.xml contains OPs example content.
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\test.xml"); 
        xdoc.Descendants("LastSyncTime")
           .Where(e => Convert.ToDateTime(e.Element("SyncTime").Value) < DateTime.Now)
           .Remove();
        Console.WriteLine(xdoc);
        xdoc.Save(@"c:\temp\test_filtered.xml");
    }
}
```

This generates the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--QTabs Data Storage-->
<SyncTimes />
```

I.e. an empty root, which is to be expected, given that all dates are smaller than `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: *Descendants* is only one of the problems, `Convert.ToDateTime(e.Element("SyncTime").Value)` is another problem which isn't addressed by the answer.

Comment: @Alex Nothing is being deleted with the above code either. Also, somehow it changed the opening SyncTimes  bracket to have a closing bracket (<SyncTimes />  ) which is resulting in an XML load error.

Comment: @DavidTunnell <SyncTimes /> is not a closing bracket, it is indicative of an empty element list i.e. all the LastSyncTime elements have been removed, it should not cause an XML load error

Comment: @Pharabus Both <SyncTimes />  and previous LastSyncTime elements are both there after I run the above.

Comment: @EZ1 there is nothing in OPs question that relates to the `DateTime` conversion. I am clearly missing your point here.

Answer (score 1):

@DavidTunnell what is your root xml element that contains everything you need? in example:

```
 //let's call the variable you use as Xdocument doc. 
            XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("LastSyncTime");
            for (int i = nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                nodes[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodes[i]);
            }
            doc.Save(path);
```

This is how i had used hope it helps.